# How to read and write cookie in dotnetnuke7?

Tags: cookies, dotnetnuke-7

I want create cookie with name and expire parameters then write into a value and read this value.
Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you will do this using javascript or jQuery.  There are jQuery packages that make it fairly simple.

Depending on the actual application, you can do ghis from inside of a module or on